# What is the most effective way to destroy cockroach and centipede size pests?

Tags: pest-control

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are some at-home options for pest control?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1030/what-are-some-at-home-options-for-pest-control)

I know one way to kill cockroach but not centipedes would be to dip pieces of potato in boric acid put them around the house in mesh bags. A way to prevent those that crawl around the house would be to wipe the boric acid onto the floor since it would leave crystals of pesticide. Are there any more effective treatment for these?

Comment: possible duplicate - http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/1030/1300

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diatomaceous earth (DE) allegedly works very good on most bugs that have an exoskeleton similar to that of an ant or cockroach.  It cuts through their shell, exposing their gooey insides to the air.  Once exposed, they quickly dehydrate and die.

Diatomaceous earth for pool filters is somewhat poisonous, so you'll be looking for food-grade DE or some other form that is nonpoisonous.

Comment: I've had food grade diatomaceous earth around the cracks that ants have been coming through, and 3 weeks later they are still coming and going as if the DE has no effect on them.