# Commercial pest control vs. DIY chemical solutions

Tags: pest-control

I can see plenty of pest-specific topics on here, including an [at-home solution](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1030/what-are-some-at-home-options-for-pest-control). However, my question relates to general pest control, and when to know to call in the big guns.

I maintain rental properties which currently have a pest control schedule. Due to pricing discounts, I also group my own home into this as well. None of the homes seem to have a real infestation issue; all are mostly preventative.

**Are the chemicals used in most pest control available over the counter? Are there any good resources for mixing your own?** The only resources I know of is big box home stores, and their options can seem limiting at times (Or at least brand-name expensive).

If I were to start to do this for the majority of pest control options; I'd save a lot of money, but was unsure if chemical potency could be matched.

Comment: Licensed applicator here.  You can't get the stuff they can get. OTOH becoming a licensed applicator is not that hard.  It's learning, not everyone can learn,  but you can, go for it.  Psst, find out what they're using.  Tell them you need MSDS for each of their chemicals.

Comment: @Harper, sounds like a good answer.

Comment: There are lots of household chemicals that work pretty well.  But the professional chemicals can be more powerful and longer lasting.  They also carry greater risks, so they can only be sold to licensed people.

Comment: It depends on the chemicals, some are. Boric acid is still used (and highly highly effective) for roaches and ants. You can get it basically pure, but it can't be used too strong or it kills before they get it back to the nest to feed larvae. For spiders, bedbugs, and flys you need something else.

Comment: We use a local professional service. However, they tell us 'you are on your own' when it comes to spiders and scorpions. I do not understand why they exclude these specific pests from their guarantee--but seems all of the locals have the same exclusions. Biggest concern is brown recluse. Scorpions HURT but they are relative rare/small. Not so with the spiders... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your state you can usually get the appropriate chemicals.

I'm certain that there are some that you cannot get without appropriate licensure but for the types used by most "spot treatment" pest management it is available. In fact you can probably apply it more effectively yourself than the typical visiting service person does.

One risk is that you use too much, which can have an ecological impact.

But, for example, you can order common pest control chemicals such as Termidor (fipronil), Indoxocarb, Imidaclorprid, Abamectin... Etc.

These sort of "pro" pesticides are not typically found at big box stores.
I've had excellent experience with DoMyOwn.com

Be smart, safe, and responsible. Try to find chemicals which are appropriately and narrowly listed for the pests you are trying to control. Mix and apply according to the recommended ratios and schedules.

Do this once and compare your experience to using a scheduled service. In my case, for spider management, I used nearly 6 gallons of mix for my entire home and it took by nearly 6 hours to clear the webs, eggs, etc. When I've had a pest-managment company they are usually here for under an hour and don't refill their sprayer even once.